# Display tree/graph

Tags: linux, graph, tree

I wrote simple C program in C++ which, given a graph and starting vertex, performs BFS on graph. I want to display it's traversal in the form of image. Which tool can I use for the same? I know that this can be easily done in python but doing BFS in C++ and producing image of BFS tree in C++ seems difficult to me. My preferred OS is linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could output a .dot format file and then render it with [`graphviz`](http://www.graphviz.org/).